# neo4j console does not start. ERROR: JAVA_HOME is incorrectly defined

Tags: ubuntu, neo4j, java-home

When I start neo4j console or neo4j-shell I get this error:

```
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is incorrectly defined as /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java (the executable /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java/bin/java does not exist)
```

On echo $JAVA_HOME I get:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java
```

This is my settings in ~/.bashrc:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java
export JAVA_HOME

PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME
export PATH
```

I have checked and tried all solutions on similar questions here and nothing worked. 
I am running Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS, and the neo4j community-3.5.0-rc01. I heve also tried on other neo4j versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice the error at the end reads `jre/bin/java/bin/java`. Notice the double `bin/java`. You need to remove `bin/java` from `JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java`. Java knows the layout of the files so it knows that `bin/java` will be below `JAVA_HOME` and you don't need to give it.